# "Постесняюсь спросить" и "не постесняюсь спросить"

Tags: фраза, слова-паразиты

Мой брат частенько использует эту фразу *постесняюсь спросить*, как вступительные слова к какой-нибудь свойственной ему скабрезной шутке, произнося её именно так:

> постесняюсь спросить

Разве не было бы "правильно" говорить что-то типа **не постесняюсь** или может быть даже **стесняясь спросить** ? Как правильно? И если есть какая-то этимология, то откуда вообще оно пошло? Можно ли считать эту фразу словами-паразитами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Постесняюсь спросить" (образованное от "стесняюсь спросить") устойчивое выражение, по факту действительно употребляемое на равне с "не постесняюсь спросить" и зачастую эти два выражения взаимозаменяемы. Но я бы не торопился делать вывод, что первое получилось усечением второго, скорее это "не постесняюсь спросить" логическое развитее изначального "стесняюсь спросить", образованное по типу "да не убоюсь" - да не постесняюсь я спросить :).

Подразумевается, что человек робеет, но всё-таки осмеливается и задаёт вопрос. В большинстве случае фраза несёт иронический оттенок, как в "стесняюсь спросить, куда это ты намылился, не сделав домашнюю работу". Спорить со словоупотреблением и говорить, что если стесняется, то чего ж спрашивает - так же продуктивно, как спорить, почему говорят "таблетки от головы", когда ясное же дело, что не от головы.

Я тот ещё авторитетный источник, но лично мне известно очень мало случаев использования обоих этих словосочетаний в досоветской периодике и литературе - буквально по пальцам руки пересчитать. Но даже если я ошибаюсь, и даже если так говорили и в XIX веке, то всё равно берусь утверждать, что пик словоупотребления пришёлся на советское и постсоветское время.

"Стесняясь спросить" - так никто от первого лица не говорит.

Ну и что касается считать ли эту фразу словом-паразитом. Тут надо дать строгое определение того, что считается словом-паразитом. Ввиду отсутствия такого определения у вас, дам своё, созвучное [данному в википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B.): слова-паразиты - это слова, употребляемые в предложении, но не несущие в данном контексте смысловой нагрузки. Их можно выкинуть из предложения без потери или изменения информационной ценности предложения.

Кстати, из той же статьи можно узнать, что, вообще говоря, это дискуссионный вопрос, действительно ли такие слова не несут никакой нагрузки и не имеют никакой функции.

В узком смысле "стесняюсь спросить" точно не слово-паразит, всё-таки ставить это словосочетания в один ряд с "это самое", "эээ" или "ммм" было бы натяжкой.

В широком - ну, давайте попробуем сравнить две фразы:

- Стесняюсь спросить, а как вы познакомились?
- А как вы познакомились?

Эквивалентны ли эти фразы? На мой взгляд нет, не эквивалентны. Но это, разумеется, вопрос метрики.

Ну и напоследок добавлю картинку - представьте, ту же картинку, но с подписью без "слов-паразитов":

[image]

Comment: Спасибо. очень глубоко и обдумано. А как бы вы заменили слова на картинке?

Answer (score 1):

"Cтесняюсь спросить, но" - это отнюдь не новый фразеологизм с ироничным смыслом вроде "Это же само по себе ясно, конечно же, отчего и якобы стеснительно спрашивать", хотя на самом деле в данном вопросе и ситуации ничего - не ясно.
Но "вот у меня такое чувство, что это же должно быть -  ясно... кому-то вроде вас, таких... ".
Отметим - что семантически тут отсутствует аспект совершенности - "стесняюсь". Ну, то есть это никак логически не мешает друг другу, "стесняться" и "спросить"; спросил, cтесняясь, и можешь дальше стесняться, стеснительный такой.

"Постесняюсь спросить, но" - это какая-то невежественная перверсия от первого варианта, появившаяся, как и некоторые иные подобные странные выражения и слова, именно - в последние десятилетия.
"Постесняться" это глагол совершенного вида, означающий, что стеснение это  окончательно стало(!) препятствием для действия, то есть - "постеснялся и не спросил, и прочь бежал от стесненья своего, плачуся горько..."
То есть такая конструкция, как  "Постесняюсь спросить, но спрошу" - бессмысленна.
"Не спрошу, но спрошу".

“не постесняюсь спросить” - а это, конечно, совершенно нормальная фраза. Как вариант 1-го или отрицание 2-го.